# what does the dot separator mean in postgres configuration parameters?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

The question is pretty much summed up in the title:
What does the dot stand for when naming a configuration parameter in postgres?

For example:

```
SET bar TO true;
```

results in `ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "bar"`, but

```
SET foo.bar TO true;
```

results in `Query returned successfully ...`

Why is that? FYI, I am using PostgreSQL 9.4

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this in the documentation. 
As per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html :

> The period (.) is used in numeric constants, and to separate schema,
>   table, and column names.

But that certainly doesn't seem to be the case here, as there is no schema, table or column with the name foo. Search_path is set to default (public).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-custom.html

> Custom options have two-part names: an extension name, then a dot,
>   then the parameter name proper, much like qualified names in SQL. An
>   example is plpgsql.variable_conflict.
>
> Because custom options may need to be set in processes that have not
>   loaded the relevant extension module, PostgreSQL will accept a setting
>   for any two-part parameter name.